# Can ministers of other denominations marry people in a Catholic church?

Tags: marriage

Can ministers from other Christian denominations, for example a United Church Reverend, perform the marriage sacrament in a Catholic Church?

Comment: Do you mean can they use a Catholic chapel to perform a protestant wedding, or can they perform one that the Catholic church will consider to be a Catholic wedding?

Comment: And are both, one or neither of the couple Catholic? (I'm looking up the rules at the moment; this might be relevant)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [United States Conference of Catholic Bishops](http://www.foryourmarriage.org/catholic-marriage/church-teachings/interfaith-marriages/),

> It’s popular, and acceptable, for an interfaith couple to invite the non-Catholic spouse’s minister to be present at the wedding. But it’s important to note that, according to canon law, only the priest may officiate at a Catholic wedding. A minister may offer a few words, but he or she may not officiate or preside at a joint ceremony.

While I wouldn't say a non-Catholic marriage in a Catholic church has never happened (and if I did, it would be hard to prove :), but it would be rare at best, akin to holding services for non-Catholic faiths in a Catholic Church.

FYI, for the a Catholic marriage to be considered sacramental, both must be Catholic, and for the marriage to be performed at all requires at least one to be Catholic. ([Source](http://www.foryourmarriage.org/catholic-marriage/faqs/))